# How to style the arrow of <details> <summary> elements?

Tags: html, css

I am using this code (also see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obLh0chn/)) to change the arrow background color on hover. However this doesn't work as the arrow only changes its color on click.

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  color: #B6B6B6;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
summary::-webkit-details-marker:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<details class="DetailContainer">
  <summary>Step by Step Guides</summary>
  <details class="DetailsOne">
    <summary>Getting Started</summary>
    <p>1. Signup for a free trial</p>
  </details>
  <details class="DetailsOne">
    <summary>Setting up a backup schedule</summary>
    <p>This step assumes you have already signed up and installed the software</p>
  </details>
</details>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace the expand ( ▶) icon of HTML5 details tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813581/replace-the-expand-icon-of-html5-details-tag)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The  `:hover` should be on the `details` tag (not the `summary`).

Try this, it will work:

```
 details:hover summary::-webkit-details-marker:hover {
     color:red;
     background:white;
 }
```