# <details><summary> arrow colour

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the arror colour only for (Level 2 and Level 3). However, I've tried this method from [How to style the arrow of <details> <summary> elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622394/how-to-style-the-arrow-of-details-summary-elements) but it doesn't work. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

```css
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  color:red;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Level 1</summary>
    <details>
        <summary>Level 2</summary>
        <details>
            <summary>Level 3</summary>
        </details>
    </details>
</details>
```

The method that I tried is inserting this to CSS.

```
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  color:red;
  background:white;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d031f765/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to apply only to sub levels, just add CSS hierarchical selector `detail detail ..`
This will be applied to sub levels but not the top most level.

```html
<details> <!-- Will not be applied -->
  ...
    <details> <!-- Will be applied -->
```

```css
details details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  color:red;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Level 1</summary>
    <details>
        <summary>Level 2</summary>
        <details>
            <summary>Level 3</summary>
        </details>
    </details>
</details>
```