# details and summary: delete or hide "arrow"

Tags: html, css, webkit, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

Code:

```
<details>
        <summary>Що зробити:</summary>
<div class="txtinsummary">
текст text текст text текст text текст text 
текст text текст text текст text текст text 
</div>
</details>
```

How to remove the "arrow" in googleBrowser?

In the FFox screenshot "arrow" does not exist.

[image: gesko]

In Google Browser is present.

[image: webkit]

Is it possible to do so as in FFox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace the expand ( ▶) icon of HTML5 details tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813581/replace-the-expand-icon-of-html5-details-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>

    <style>

    summary{
    display: inline;
    {

    </style>

</head>

<body>

        <details>

        <summary>

        <div">menu1</div>

        </summary>

        <div>
        link or image or submenu
        </div>

        </details>

<br><br>
!!! I'm not sure that all browsers will correctly accept such code.

<br><br>
I did this on my site.

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}

...is the magic spell you are looking for!

Comment: This put me on the right track. Nowadays `::marker` is in the standard, but `display: none` is not allowed, thus has no effect. But one can use `::marker { content: ""; }` to remove the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It is done with styling unordered list tag . To do this we can use content property in conjunction with the :before pseudo-element. It is demonstrated in below code:

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "\2023 \0020";
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
   <ul>
    <li style="text-decoration:underline">Topic</li>
   </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

{  content: "\2023 \0020"; }  /* 2023 is hex code of arrow bullet style */
But Before ,We have to declare ul { list-style:none } to remove default list styling.

Comment: if you have any doubts please ask

Comment: no. I have no  ul tag. BUT  I understood your approach. I need to replace the arrow with a space. I have completed my question. I did not check your method :(. Today I will check.

Comment: Already checked. In Ffox and in Google-chrom there is an arrow.

Comment: Yes.It will be interesting to know how you solved it