# Styling the HTML5 summary arrow for Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox

I want to use the HTML5 [summary element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-summary-element) on Firefox. By default, the element is styled with a triangular arrow (see an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary)). I want to change the color of this arrow. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813581/replace-the-expand-icon-of-html5-details-tag) explains how this can be done for Chrome, but after testing it does not work for Firefox.

Is there a way to change the color of the arrow of the summary element with Firefox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently on FF 68 I am able to customise the marker by doing:

```css
summary::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

Make sure to try to apply the styles in a generic way *(AKA avoid nesting classes so you are sure that the traverse is not a problem)*

[image: Screenshot of details marker customization]

Also, as you probably are adding styles cross browser the below snippet **doesn't work properly**

```css
summary::marker,
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    color: $primary;
}
```

**Instead I have to define it separately** like so:

```css
summary::marker {
  color: $primary;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  color: $primary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that's the best answer currently -- no need for an additional `span`, no need to redefine the arrow manually. BTW, I guess the reason why you have to define separately is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816764/invalid-css-selector-causes-rule-to-be-dropped-what-is-the-rationale (because each of Firefox and Chrome won't understand the other's selector).

Answer (score 14):

Removing the caret in Firefox and Chrome:

```css
details summary { list-style-type: none; } /* Firefox */
details summary::-webkit-details-marker { display: none; } /* Chrome */
details summary::marker { display: none; }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Open/Close</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
</details>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list-style-type` in Firefox (and perhaps Edge/Safari) to style the arrow [[css-tricks]](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-that-details-summary-is-the-easiest-way-ever-to-make-an-accordion/).

```
/* replace with custom image */
summary {
  list-style-image: url(right-arrow.svg);
}

/* hide arrow */
summary {
  list-style-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Hide default arrow */     
summary::-moz-list-bullet {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: block;
}
/* Create customizable arrow */       
summary:before {
   content: ' ';
   border: solid #939faa;
   border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

http://www.otsukare.info/2016/04/19/summary-details

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha: if you use normalizer (`normalize.css` etc.) or something similar, in order to hide the `::marker` in Firefox in **macOS**, you have to style both `<summary>` and the `::marker`:

```
  summary {
    display: block;
  }

  summary::marker {
    display: none;
  }
```

Otherwise `<summary>` will get its styles from elsewhere (normalizer etc.) and it could be something like `display: list-item`, which will prevent you from hiding the marker.

Answer (score 0):

```css
details > summary:first-of-type {
    color: blue;
}
```

This CSS will work on Firefox, but you will still need to use the original method for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, but this changes the color of the whole `summary` element (not just the arrow). That said, based on this, I guess I could style the `summary` element (with the arrow), and then put the actual contents of the `summary` element in a `span` that I would style differently. If you think that this is the best solution, feel free to edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround to change the color of the `summary` arrow in Firefox is simply to change the color of the entire `summary` element, and put the contents of the element in a `span` styled in a different way.

For instance:

```
<style type="text/css">
summary {
  color: red;
}
.summary_contents {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

And:

```
<details>
  <summary>
    <span class="summary_contents">foobar</span>
  </summary>
  [...]
</details>
```