# Where I can get all CSS elements and properties spec reference listed as to each HTML(XHTML) tag?

Tags: html, css

I am studying HTML and CSS standard to know possible API on Web programming, so tried to find the standard document. I found all possible [HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp), [CSS elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), and [CSS properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp). After had been reading that, I have got three confusing things about HTML and CSS standard concepts.

1. I don't think all HTML tag support same CSS elements and properties, so I want to know all possible CSS elements and properties per each HTML tag, especially for pseudo elements and classes, because it's not written on HTML file. For example, When I want to change `summary` style, I can use the elements like `hover` or `-webkit-details-marker`, and properties like `color`. I only know some classes and properties that I saw in other people's code. However, I want to find all the possible elements and properties list documentation for `summary` tag.
2. I saw the element `hover` at [CSS elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), but can find the 
   `-webkit-details-marker` element at that link. `-webkit-details-marker` was found at [study blog](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/use-details-summary-elements)(not the standard documentation). Why does `-webkit-details-marker` not exist in [CSS elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) list? Is `-webkit-details-marker` not the standard element?
3. `-webkit` properties are not found at [CSS properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp), but [MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions#WebKit-prefixed_properties_on_the_standards_track) says some part of `-webkit` properties is standard. I couldn't know why standard `-webkit` properties are not listed in [CSS properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp). As I know, w3schools list standard HTML and CSS references.

Could you give me any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Much of your question makes little sense, could you clarify what you're asking? What I can help with is -webkit prefixed css rules are [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Comment: Well w3school is just some site with tutorials and not linked to actual css specs site. You could read thru https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html but it will be less helpful than you think. It is best to start coding and learn step by step, coding is done best when you use it to learn.

Comment: @Sam F  Your advice about vendor prefixs is helpful to me. Also, I changed the title to clarify my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Huangism I understand what I missed.. I appreciate your reply. By any chance, Could you let me know the accutal css spec link?

Comment: It's in the link I have above, the w3.org site is the proper site for all css specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site has more info and resources about working with this tag, browser support, and build resources: https://caniuse.com/#feat=details. It may give you some more paths of research.

If you're more concerned about styling, [try this answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813581/replace-the-expand-icon-of-html5-details-tag).