# Can I replace the expand icon (▶) of the <details> element in XHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

In the questions

- [Can I replace the expand icon (▶) of the <details> element in absence of <summary> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917354/can-i-replace-the-expand-icon-of-the-details-element-in-absence-of-summar)
- [Can I replace the expand icon (▶) of the <details> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813581/can-i-replace-the-expand-icon-of-the-details-element)

information was requested about the handling of the expand icon in HTML, the solution used was:

```
details>summary {
  list-style-type: none;
}

details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display: none;
}

details>summary::before {
    content: "\25ba";
    padding-right:4px;
    font-size: 80%;
}

details[open]>summary::before {
    content: "\25bc";
    padding-right:4px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

thought this is not working in XHTML documents.

So the question is: how to set the icon in a XHTML document?

- preferably in css but also js is possible
- preferably with and without `<summary>` element

Comment: Are these elements supported in xhtml?

Comment: Good question  as far as I know it should work as the `<details> element is working in Firefox, Chrome and Edge for the html version and the xhtml version though the xhtml version doesn't pick up the mentioned css settings.

Comment: May you create a [mcve]? What kind of xhtml are you using?

Comment: I wilt try to create a  MWE.

Comment: Thanks for having me make a MWE, it looks like my, generated, code contains `<details > <p><summary> The summary 3</summary> The details</p> </details>` and this should be `<details > <summary> The summary 3</summary> <p> The details</p> </details>` It looks like a file with extension `.html` has no problems, but a file with extension `.xhtml` does. I have to investigate further...

Comment: `xhtml` is very restrictive. Browsers will try to render even invalid `html` on the other hand